# How to crawl a large list of urls?

Tags: web-crawler

I have a massive list of urls. It looks something like this:

```
www.example.com/api/users/1.json
www.example.com/api/users/2.json
www.example.com/api/users/3.json
```

And continues about 400,000 times. The intent is to find a specific string of text in all of the pages. Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Comment: What OS? This could be done with a fairly easy script in Linux using a loop to read the fe, then wget or curl to download the contents and grep to parse it.

Comment: I can run Linux on a VM.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with this project but googling I did find one called [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/). It's written in Python and is discussed in several places, such as these:

- on StackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986899/best-performance-for-scrapy, where it's suggested that you run Scrapy as a daemon, `scrapyd`.
- [Develop your first web crawler in Python Scrapy](https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/develop-your-first-web-crawler-in-python-scrapy-6b2ee4baf954)
- Scrapy example - [quotesbot](https://github.com/scrapy/quotesbot)

The 2nd link above shows this example as well:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
class ElectronicsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "electronics"
    allowed_domains = ["www.olx.com.pk"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.olx.com.pk/computers-accessories/',
        'https://www.olx.com.pk/tv-video-audio/',
        'https://www.olx.com.pk/games-entertainment/'
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_css=('.pageNextPrev',)),
             callback="parse_item",
             follow=True),)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print('Processing..' + response.url)
```

You could amend the above to either include all your URLs or put them into a separate file, and read that file in through Python.

If I were you I'd be inclined to start with the 3rd link, quotesbot, since this project sounds eerily similar to what you're ultimately trying to accomplish.